# Local setting of black theme in any MS Office application overrides account-wide setting

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, themes

My MS office license is via an office 365 account, with a number of other users using the theme 'colorful'. I had to reinstall my MS office, and now, when going to options in any MS office application and changing the theme under "personalize your copy of MS Office" to 'black', the theme switches for all users.

When I remove the account, my default setting goes back to 'black' but when logged into the account all my MS office applications are set to 'colorful'.

What is happening here? How can I locally override the account settings properly, without changing the theme for all other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Office Theme to "Use system settings".

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

Select “File” and then select “Account” in the pane that appears.

[image]

Select the menu under “Office Background” or “Office Theme,” browse through the different background and themes with a live preview, and choose the ones you want.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this changes the theme for all users linked to the account.